Importing mysql file fails printing last line and I find ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^ on that line
I am trying to import some relatively large databases, over 100 GB dump file.
When I try to import the dump files with a command like:
mysql -h localhost -u username -p dbname < backup.sql
after some hours it fails and it prints last line, I cannot see upper if there is a start of error, because I am in screen and screen only shows end of output.
What I get there is a dump line like:
,('daga88.bet',0,1,1,0,6,257078,-132553,1662996449,179113,598788,NULL,NULL,0,0,1712710000,NULL,1710150000,1652513002,NULL),('daga88.com',1,1,1,0,6,266021,0,1672675038,266021,266021,NULL,NULL,0,0,1672675098,0,1708690000,1672687391,NULL),('daga88.live',0,1,1,0,6,471459,0,1655308937,471459,471459,NULL,NULL,0,0,1707210000,0,1710150000,1655345529,NULL),('daga888.live',0,1,1,0,7,344485,0,1655736029,344485,344485,NULL,NULL,0,0,1707640000,0,1710150000,1655753000,NULL),('daga88vn.net',1,1,1,0,8,620701,0,1648227623,620701,620701,NULL,NULL,0,0,1697470000,0,1715620000,1652513003,NULL),('daga99.net',1,1,1,0,6,692132,0,1582125484,329203,746817,'not found',NULL,0,1683060000,1712150000,0,1713570000,1652513047,NULL),('daga999.com',1,1,1,0,7,382440,0,1630243622,382440,382440,NULL,NULL,0,0,1716600000,0,1717490000,1652513049,NULL),('daga999.net',1,1,1,0,7,630164,0,1581778443,630164,630164,NULL,NULL,0,0,1709620000,0,1714150000,1652513051,NULL),('dagaa.in',0,1,0,0,5,219833,-76305,1646767866,219833,330146,NULL,NULL,0,0,1701070000,0,1710150000,1652513053,NULL),('dagaa.mx',0,1,0,0,5,28433'.

Then I open the dump file with vi editor to look at that line and I see this:
('dagaa.mx',0,1,0,0,5,28433^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
I don't see any error in mysql log. Maybe an error might have been printed at export time.
What could that mean ? I assume my dump is corrupted ? What could cause this ?
I remember I seen this before but cannot remember the cause / fix.
Maybe this can be fixed by tuning some mysql values to process more data at once ? like innodb_redo_log_capacity or other parameters ?
Is hard to "try" things because this happens after 10-12 hours of processing (importing .sql file).

have you looked into the mysql error log, to see if there is a problem with temp space or memory?

Sounds like you are using CHAR(..) where you should be using VARCHAR(..)

@RickJames can you give me more details ? You mentioned that as an optimisation /  best practice, or something that can cause this bug ? I think I found the cause, will post another comment.

@nbk I didn't see anything in the sql log while importing but I am 99% sure this happen because I was dumping the .sql file on a remote storage mounted with cifs, when I dumped directly on disk I was able to import same data just fine.

I am answering my own question since I am 99% sure this was the cause and I previously ran into this without remembering the solution :)
So if the .sql file is dumped into a remote storage, e.g mounted with cifs with commands in /etc/fstab then the dump file is eider corrupted or encoded inproperly.
When I dumpped same .sql file directly on local disk, then moved to same remote storage, then to new server and imported on new server, then this worked just fine.
If anyone has tips about this feel free to post, not sure if this is because of encoding, mount options, network instability, etc.
